# How to count how many time a word occurs in an xml file

Tags: xml, linux, text, text-editor

I was given the task of doing quality check on a machine translation xml file. The translations are from English to a foreign language. I have about 2000 translation blocks in the file and I have to check 200 of them by adding my remarks in the block enclosed in a < comment > tag with a quality attribute. Is there a linux command or some text editor out there which can count the number of comment tags I add or just the number of time the word '/comment' occurs so I don't have to keep track manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

grep '/comment' yourfile.xml -o | wc -l

Comment: Doesn't `grep` send `wc` entire lines?  And wouldn't you get a false result if the word occurred more than once on a line?

Answer (score 2):

This XSLT stylesheet can be run on any platform and will tell you how many comment elements there are in the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//comment)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you add a XSLT processing instruction at the top of the XML file that points to this XSLT( e.g. `<?xml-stylesheet href="countComments.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>` ), then you could just load the XML file in a browser and see the number displayed.

Answer (score 0):

your tag says linux, so i assume you have *nix tools like awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="/comment"){++c} } }END{print "total: "c}' xmlfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the `</comment>` doesn't occur more than once per line, just use `grep -c "</comment>"`. Example:

```
[~/.logs]> grep -c ldap johnf.2010-02-12.log
103
```

This searches for the string `ldap` in the file `johnf.2010-02-12.log`. The string appears on 103 distinct lines.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the comments appear on their own line, you could try

```
cat file | grep -c comment
```

The -c stands for 'count'.